# How to create AlertDialog in androidx.appcompat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, androidx

Have next import:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
```

And create dialog as follows:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val adb = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
                .setTitle(R.string.actions_rename_connection)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.actions_ok, this)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.actions_cancel, this)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_name, null)
        val dialog = adb.setView(view).create()
        dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
        return dialog
    }
```

But I'm not satisfied `activity!!`.

For example, with another import i create dialog as follows:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog

 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.MaterialThemeDialog)
                .setTitle(R.string.in_app_settings_language)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.actions_ok) { _, _ -> presenterContract.onOkClick() }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.actions_cancel) { _, _ -> closeView() }
                .create()
    }
```

Q: there are some solutions where we can use `activity` in androidx ?

Comment: I think that activity is a nullable in AndroidX, so you could use activity?.let{} to avoid the usage of activity!!

Comment: @RobertLaFondue i can't. Because when I try to get my dialogue back, he'll demand type `Dialog`

Comment: Use activity?.let{} and return a nullable Dialog (Dialog?), because you can't be sure to return a safe Dialog if your activity can be null

Comment: "But I'm not satisfied activity!!" -- what exactly is the problem? `getActivity()` (the Java method behind the `activity` Kotlin property) is marked as possibly returning `null`. Neither version of `AlertDialog.Builder()` will work with a `null` value, but only the AndroidX version has the `@NotNull` annotation to trigger a compile error. If you pass `null` to the framework `AlertDialog.Builder()`, you will crash at runtime. In both cases, you need to check whether `activity` is `null` -- it's just that in the AndroidX case, you are forced to do so.

Comment: @RobertLaFondue i can t return `Dialog?` in override method.

Comment: @CommonsWare "you will crash at runtime" - bad practice!

Comment: "i can t return Dialog? in override method" -- that's an unfortunate limitation of the API. Ideally, it should support `null` and cleanly tidy up if you return `null`, as an indication that you were unable to create the dialog for some reason. You could switch to showing a dialog-themed activity instead of using `AlertDialog` and `DialogFragment`. Otherwise, AFAIK, you are stuck with the API that you have.

Answer (score 4):

**android.app.AlertDialog** use @Nullable activity. IDE is not angry using activity for this reason.

but

**androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog** use @NonNull activity. You should use !! or null check for activity

I think you should use it this way

```
activity?.let {
                AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.MaterialThemeDialog)
                .setTitle(R.string.in_app_settings_language)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.actions_ok) { _, _ -> presenterContract.onOkClick() }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.actions_cancel) { _, _ -> closeView() }
                .create()   
}
```

Comment: Great one, I'm new to Kotlin and I still need to get used to it. This stuff has been driving me crazy for a while, applicationContext was just not working, "let" did the job perfectly.